# ASP.NET Core (ASP.NET 5) running a custom command to launch Node http-server

Tags: visual-studio-2015, command, asp.net-core, httpserver

In an AngularJS with TypeScript application I am using an ASP.NET-Core application (previously known as ASP.NET 5) to serve static files so my Startup.cs for MyProject looks like this, although this should apply only for Kestrel and IIS as they look into `wwwroot` folder to serve whatever is there:

```
public class Startup
    {
        public Startup()
        {
        }

        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
        }

        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
        {
            app.UseIISPlatformHandler();
            app.UseDefaultFiles(); //to browse index.html or default.html
            app.UseStaticFiles();
        }

        public static void Main(string[] args) => WebApplication.Run<Startup>(args);
    }
```

I am also using gulp to compile typescript into javascript and to minify and deploy files under `wwwroot`.

However during development I'd like to run the NodeJs http-server under `~/src/MyProject` without having to compile/minify so that it serves whatever is under `~/src/MyProject`.

I can do that manually from the command line by running:
`c:\>proj\src\MyProject>http-server`

The question is, **how can I configure a command in my Project so that it launches the `http-server` not under wwwroot but under `c:\>proj\src\MyProject` when I click on the Run button in VS2015**?

```
"commands": {
    "web": "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.Kestrel",
    "cargo-server": "http-server" //this does not launch the server
  },
```

**UPDATE**: I couldn't find a way to add a custom command that references a class and the class runs a CMD command (that could be a good option if possible) so that VS2015 can run this command as it currently runs IIS Express.. but as a workaround I am using Gulp and a task to serve my code at the specified folder.

```
gulp.task('serve', function () {
var options = {
    continueOnError: false, // default = false, true means don't emit error event 
    pipeStdout: false, // default = false, true means stdout is written to file.contents 
    customTemplatingThing: "test" // content passed to gutil.template() 
};
var reportOptions = {
    err: true, // default = true, false means don't write err 
    stderr: true, // default = true, false means don't write stderr 
    stdout: true // default = true, false means don't write stdout 
}
var port = 8080;
var url = 'localhost';
log('http-server running on port ' + port);
gulp
    .src(config.client)
    .pipe($.exec('http-server -d -o -a ' + url + ' -p ' + port, options))
    .pipe($.exec.reporter(reportOptions));
});
```

Comment: What happens if you run `dnx cargo-server`? Isn't that the result that you're expecting?

Comment: No. It doesn't run from command line:
```dnx cargo-server 
Error: Unable to load application or execute command 'http-server'. Available commands: web, cargo-server.```

Comment: ohhhh... I just noticed what you're trying to do. That will not work. You have to launch http-server yourself using another script. Commands in project.json are entry points for your application and they must be .net applications

Comment: Thank you. That explains it :)